# My dog, Jack Russell, is jealous of others showing me affection

Tags: dogs, training, psychology, aggression

We have a ~10 month old, 5 and a bit kilograms, Jack Russell bitch, "Smudge".

Smudge is hardly perfect, but one piece of behavior is a bit worrying.

She had tended to yap and feint-lunge at me/us if I give my other half a kiss, but as neither of us is remotely afraid of her and we're adept at grabbing her and reasserting authority it didn't seem a big deal.

Until - My little niece sat next to me, held my arm and put her head on my shoulder. Smudge did the yap-yap and feint-lunge!  We quickly experimented with my partner and my mother each giving me a hug; same result, **Smudge gets yappy and feint-lunges at whoever is showing me affection.**

**We want to train this tendency right out of her.  How?**

Appendix:

- She is basically great with all humans and dogs, but can be very keen to rush up and say hello.
- She can get frustrated if she's decided the attention she's getting is inadequate, or she can't reach someone (or some dog) she's decided she *has* to meet.
- She might have a tendency to get yappy and jumpy with anyone who shows nerves around her. Or maybe who just *seems* to be ignoring her. (She's so damn cute, this very rarely happens.)
- The vast majority of her interactions with people and dogs are on our local meadows and beaches. We're fortunate that almost every person is also "doggy", confident, and friendly with her, and every dog is at least well socialized and usually up for some chasing and/or ruff and tumble.

Answer (score 1):

This situation is more complicated than you might realize, hence the answer is more vague than I'd like. But let's analyze the matter at hand:

### The Behavior

Objectively speaking your dog actively tries to disrupt anyone giving attention or physical contact to you. You interpreted this as her being **jealous**, but it could also be:

- that she is **possessive** of you and tries to defend her possession against others or
- that she's **insecure or anxious** (you described her as nervous) and your cuddling anyone triggers anxiety in her for whatever reason. She tries to disrupt your cuddling to make the situation return to normal.
- Or some completely different reason that I overlooked now.

You see, it's hard to diagnose this kind of problem without seeing the dog and testing some triggers.

Let me warn you against humanizing her. Jealousy is a very human emotion (and yes, dogs can be jealous as well), but a dog brain works different and she could feel something entirely different than what you interpret. Expecting her to behave like a human results in a closed mindset that might not let you realize her true thought process.

### What Could Happen

If you do nothing against her behavior but disengage the affectionate contact due to her yapping, you reinforce her behavior. She wants you to stop hugging. If you stop hugging (even if you scold her) she got what she wanted.

If she's the nervous / anxious type, the worst that can happen is that your hugging someone reinforces her anxiety. If she gets scolded every time you hug, she learns that hugging is followed by scolding, therefore she gets nervous and yappy when she sees you hugging, which prompts you to scold her...

Either way it's a vicious circle of reinforcement.

### What Should Happen

I agree that you should train this behavior out of her, but since I cannot diagnose the actual problem, I cannot give you advice on how to do this. There's the risk that you could increase the problem if you misunderstand the cause.

That's why I reccomend you contact a local dog trainer (not the puppy school type, but someone who analyzes the behavior of and trains problematic dogs). They should come to your home and see her actions first hand, then explain the reasons for her behavior to you and advise you trainings to discourage her yapping.

In the meantime I think it would be beneficial for her to experience delayed gratification. That means you teach her to sit and stay on command, even from a distance. Then you introduce short (no more than 2 seconds at the beginning) waiting periods into your play: throw the ball and make her wait 2 seconds before she can run and snatch it. Or put a treat in front of her but make her wait before she can eat it. After training for some time (several weeks at least) you can increase the time she has to wait.

This is not just a neat trick to show off, it teaches her control over her impulses and that she doesn't have to get everything *right now now NOW!*, but that she can be a little bit calmer and still have fun. For her to learn that, you must always reward her patience (never let her wait only for the treat to be snatched away).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Elmy that your Jack is possessive. Jack Russells are a very aggressive breed. They are an adults dog. I do not agree that the should not be humanized.I have had Jack Russells since 2002. All have been humanized to an extent. The major thing they are not allowed to do is eat human food. I do not have beggars at the dinner table. Other than that they are treated as children. They sleep with us, sit in our laps. They are allowed to get on certain chairs, actually they claim them. I allow that with my current set of 10 yo twin girls. I did not allow it with their predecessors, 2 boys (one lived till 17, the other till 13).

What needs to happen is inclusion. Allow your little girl to be part of your kiss. Have her sit in his lap when you kiss. Then each of you give her a little kiss or some loving petting. It will probably be a little difficult and awkward at first. Slowly she will realize he is not replacing her in your affection. How long? Don't know, but Jacks are very smart.So I do not expect very long. For a while you will need to get back to her after you show affection to another where she is not included.

This is a temporary problem. As she grows and is included while a puppy, she will need less and less reinsurance. However, it will never go completely away. I consider that a good thing as they make me happy especially during a crappy day. They will want to be with any one who regularly comes home. Guests are a different story. There they have to be trained not to be aggressive. The younger you start the easier it is. You have to remember Jacks are naturally aggressive dogs. They need to be trained social behavior.

When you walk them they need to be on a tight leash. They choose their friends. They also not afraid of any dog, even ones who would eat them alive. Thus you need to pay attention to them. Additionally, until they get old (somewhere between 8-12) they need lots of walking as they are a very energetic breed.

For me I would have no other breed. Hopefully, Smudge will grow up to be a loving member of your family.